# Data-table columns are not aligning to right

Tags: javascript, datatables, bootstrap-4

I am working on data-tables I have successfully created one but facing issue with alignment of data to right of some columns

**Snippet**

```js
var data=[
    {
      "amount": 518212,
      "billdate": "2018-08-04",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 104801,
      "billdate": "2018-08-04",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 138151,
      "billdate": "2018-08-04",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 628358,
      "billdate": "2018-08-05",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 115223,
      "billdate": "2018-08-05",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 134107,
      "billdate": "2018-08-05",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 177866,
      "billdate": "2018-08-06",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 66095,
      "billdate": "2018-08-06",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 284069,
      "billdate": "2018-08-07",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 58789,
      "billdate": "2018-08-07",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 67886,
      "billdate": "2018-08-07",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 313128,
      "billdate": "2018-08-08",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 59939,
      "billdate": "2018-08-08",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 68558,
      "billdate": "2018-08-08",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 321797,
      "billdate": "2018-08-09",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 64431,
      "billdate": "2018-08-09",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 57352,
      "billdate": "2018-08-09",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 323556,
      "billdate": "2018-08-10",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 58772,
      "billdate": "2018-08-10",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 43722,
      "billdate": "2018-08-10",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 464127,
      "billdate": "2018-08-11",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 93110,
      "billdate": "2018-08-11",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 62213,
      "billdate": "2018-08-11",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 626772,
      "billdate": "2018-08-12",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 126933,
      "billdate": "2018-08-12",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 63119,
      "billdate": "2018-08-12",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 167391,
      "billdate": "2018-08-13",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 27110,
      "billdate": "2018-08-13",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 275115,
      "billdate": "2018-08-14",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 58633,
      "billdate": "2018-08-14",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 37920,
      "billdate": "2018-08-14",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    }
  ];
  var columndef=[{title:"amount",data:"amount"},{title:"billdate",data:"billdate"},{title:"outlet",data:"outlet"}];
     $('#tbl').DataTable({
        columns:columndef,
      data : data,
          scrollY:        '30vh',
          scrollCollapse: true,
          paging:         true,
          "columnDefs" : [ {
     "targets" : [0],
       className : 'dt-body-right',
     "render" : function(data, type, row) {
      return Number(data).toLocaleString('en-IN', {
       maximumFractionDigits : 2,

      });
      
     }
        
    }]
     
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.18/r-2.2.2/sc-1.5.0/datatables.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.18/r-2.2.2/sc-1.5.0/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table id="tbl"></table>
```

I am also putting comma separator for Indian currency that is working fine but not the alignment.

I am trying to align the first column i.e amount to right but not getting it right, I don't know where I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing it right but not including the required `CDN` `Link`.

Do include

`<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />`

**check the snippet**

```js
var data=[
    {
      "amount": 518212,
      "billdate": "2018-08-04",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 104801,
      "billdate": "2018-08-04",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 138151,
      "billdate": "2018-08-04",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 628358,
      "billdate": "2018-08-05",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 115223,
      "billdate": "2018-08-05",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 134107,
      "billdate": "2018-08-05",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 177866,
      "billdate": "2018-08-06",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 66095,
      "billdate": "2018-08-06",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 284069,
      "billdate": "2018-08-07",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 58789,
      "billdate": "2018-08-07",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 67886,
      "billdate": "2018-08-07",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 313128,
      "billdate": "2018-08-08",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 59939,
      "billdate": "2018-08-08",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 68558,
      "billdate": "2018-08-08",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 321797,
      "billdate": "2018-08-09",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 64431,
      "billdate": "2018-08-09",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 57352,
      "billdate": "2018-08-09",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 323556,
      "billdate": "2018-08-10",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 58772,
      "billdate": "2018-08-10",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 43722,
      "billdate": "2018-08-10",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 464127,
      "billdate": "2018-08-11",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 93110,
      "billdate": "2018-08-11",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 62213,
      "billdate": "2018-08-11",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 626772,
      "billdate": "2018-08-12",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 126933,
      "billdate": "2018-08-12",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 63119,
      "billdate": "2018-08-12",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 167391,
      "billdate": "2018-08-13",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 27110,
      "billdate": "2018-08-13",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 275115,
      "billdate": "2018-08-14",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 58633,
      "billdate": "2018-08-14",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 37920,
      "billdate": "2018-08-14",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    }
  ];
  var columndef=[{title:"amount",data:"amount"},{title:"billdate",data:"billdate"},{title:"outlet",data:"outlet"}];
     $('#tbl').DataTable({
        columns:columndef,
      data : data,
          scrollY:        '30vh',
          scrollCollapse: true,
          paging:         true,
          "columnDefs" : [ {
     "targets" : [0],
       className : 'dt-body-right',
     "render" : function(data, type, row) {
      return Number(data).toLocaleString('en-IN', {
       maximumFractionDigits : 2,

      });
      
     }
        
    }]
     
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.18/r-2.2.2/sc-1.5.0/datatables.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.18/r-2.2.2/sc-1.5.0/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table id="tbl"></table>
```